# Autowired field is null in RestController

Tags: java, spring, autowired, spring-restcontroller

I have a project with several modules and my aim is to reuse the services defined in the 'core'  module in other modules.
For exemple the module 'batch' is able to reuse the methods defined in the 'core' module (declared as @Autowired) by loading the application context class (via AnnotationConfigApplicationContext) which loads and wires the 'core' services. So far so good.

The problem arise when I want to do the same thing in my 'rest controller' module. The 'core' service is declared as @Autowired just as in the 'batch' module, but when the controller tries to use it the following exception is shown:

> java.lang.NullPointerException
> itix.rest.itixrestservice.RestRessourceController.getRealMethod(RestRessourceController.java:40)
> sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
> sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
> sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
> org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory$1.invoke(ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.java:81)
> org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher$1.run(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:144)

The thing I have not get yet, which I think is the reason for the failure, is how to load the application context (and so wire my services) in the 'rest controller' context.

This 'rest controller' module just need to expose some endpoints, the view part is delegated to another module which will retrieve and display the endpoint contents. Controller code is as following :

> ```
> @Component 
> @ComponentScan(basePackages = {"itix.core.service","itix.rest.itixrestservice"}) 
> @Path("/controller") 
> public class RestRessourceController extends AnnotationConfigApplicationContext {
>
> @Autowired
> MatchService matchService;
>
> @GET
> @Path("getReal")
> @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
> public ResponseEntity<List<Match>> getReal() {
>     List<Match> allMatches = matchService.getAllMatches();
>     return ResponseEntity.ok(allMatches);
> }
> ```

The service is declared as follows:

> ```
> @Service 
> @Transactional(readOnly = true) public class MatchServiceImpl implements MatchService {
>
> @Autowired
> MatchDao matchDao;
> ```

and the dao :

> ```
> @Repository public class MatchDaoImpl implements MatchDao {
>
> @Autowired
> private SessionFactory sessionFactory;
> ```

And this is the call to the controller which raises the error:

> http://localhost:8889/itix-rest-service/rest/controller/getReal

By the way the same call to a different method which does not call the autowired service works fine.

I have found some infos using spring MVC but this is not I want to achieve.
What am I missing ? Is there any link I should look at ?

Comment: I think you need to add some code (and poms) to your question, otherwise it is hard to help you by looking at a stack trace without any code context.

Comment: Please post some code. We need to know which annotations are used in the controller. What your context looks like? How you are using autowiring? Maybe post modified code (obscuring any details you don't want to share) so we can help you.

Comment: I have updated the question with the information reequired. Please let me know if anyhting else is needed ?

Comment: Do you have the source code for the service available? Is it supposed to be "Spring compatible"?

Comment: I have updated the question with service and dao. Is that enough ?

Answer (score 1):

(disclaimer: I am working with the info that is given).

By default `@Autowired MatchService matchService` should never result in a `NullPointerException` in Spring as the default behaviour of `@Autowired` is to be non-optional - a `BeanNotFoundException` should have been raised.

This is showing that `@Autowired` is not working at all in your controller class.
Looking at your controller which is using `@ComponentScan` and `extends AnnotationConfigApplicationContext` I would guess you are mixing your controller and main Spring Boot class which can't work. The main Spring Boot class cannot `@Autowire` beans as it's used to initialize Spring Boot itself and thus is not a managed bean.

Removing the `@ComponentScan` and `extends AnnotationConfigApplicationContext` and moving to a separate main class should solve your issues:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"itix.core.service","itix.rest.itixrestservice"}) 
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

}
```

The solution should be similiar even if you are not using Spring Boot - don't mix your controller and `AnnotationConfigApplicationContext` class.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, that cleared up a few things. What I still don't get it is the link between the Application class and the controller (the class defining the @Paths).
I have packaged my projet as war to expose the endpoints. At which step of the war deployment the main() of the Application is called to detect the beans ?

Comment: You can read up about tomcats servlet detection here: https://www.mulesoft.com/tcat/tomcat-deploy-procedures